# Handling segues and next screen of my story board

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
if (self.txtusername.text.isEmpty)
{
    (UIAlertView(title: "Fields cant be empty", message: "Please Enter username and password",
     delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show())
     self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
else if (range==nil)
{
    (UIAlertView(title: "Invalid Email Id", message: "Type mail id like xxx@yyy.zzz", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show())
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Am using this code while login to alert the user but alert message is poping up to my next seen...
I want that alert in login page and it should not show my next screen how to do that?

Comment: open new screen on click of alertview's button click event.

Comment: can u please elaborate?

Comment: what about the rest of the code of this function?, maybe the issue is not in this block of code

Comment: if (self.txtusername.text.isEmpty)
        {
            
            (UIAlertView(title: "Fields cant be empty", message: "Please Enter username and password",
             delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show())
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            
Am showing this alert message if user didn't give credentials at login but that alert is coming at my home page it should come at login right? that i am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.

```
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Fields cant be empty"
                                                    message:@"Please Enter username and password"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex (NSInteger)buttonIndex** 
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0){
         //your code...
    }
    else{
         NSLog(@"cancel");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
if(responseData != "\"Valid user\"")
                {
                var alertView:UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alertView.title = "Failed"
                    alertView.message = responseData
                    alertView.delegate = self
                    alertView.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                    alertView.show()
                    //self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                    //let vc = LoginController()

                    return;
                }
```

May help you very easily.

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: this thing you also tell him by comments....and you have to explain what this code means....just copy and paste is not the stackoverflow is all about

Comment: if you do `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` this in your condition call, then your current view will get down(means dismissed), and navigate to parent of current view

Comment: I m not getting your view configuration. Put full function for more detail base.

Comment: from where you are getting parameter?

Comment: put full function where segue is called. so I can help u in better way

Comment: Remove your segue from button, put it on View which contains that button, n don't forget to put identifier(like "gotoHome") in Property Inspector. You can call that segue when your validation get correct like `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoHome" sender:self];`

Comment: We can go in discussion, can you do that?

Comment: Goto your storyboard, Remove segue from your Login button, now Select the view LoginViewController, select it from TOP Yellow Circle, and strech seg from that to next view, Name it "gotoHome". 

After your validate get successfully complete, in else part put the code `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"gotoHome" sender:self];`

Comment: i need 1 more help from you i have to handle the userid throughout the application like how we use session in c# can you help me to do this?